# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '< URL HERE >' : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to connect to a WSDL feed, this works fine from my local machine (Windows) but not from the web server (Linux). When I attempt a connection I get this error:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
>   Couldn't load from
>   'http://services.clfdistribution.com:8080/CLFWebOrdering_Test/WebOrdering.asmx?WSDL'
>   : failed to load external entity

I've compared the phpinfo readouts from both machines and everything seems to match except that the working one (local PC) is PHP 5.5.36 and the non-working one (web server) is PHP 7.0.22

I've tried various fixes that I've found and nothing seems to work. Some other feeds do work but not the one I need to connect to.

We have cPanel access but no ability to edit PHP configuration (host is SiteGround).

Comment: I just changed the web server to PHP 5.5.38 and it made no difference so the PHP version is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been resolved - Siteground were blocking port 8080, once this restriction was removed it all worked fine.